# Nginx location blocks not matching as intended?

Tags: regex, url, redirect, nginx

We recently made a new website which broke a lot of the ugly URLs from the old site. Now those ugly URLs get a 404 response. We want to fix a few of these links as they've broken some of our partner's websites which used to link to them.

In my nginx config I have:

```
location = /index.cfm?pagepath=Grain_Marketing&id=15404 {
    return 301 $scheme://www.[redacted].com/grain-marketing/;
}

location /index.cfm {
    return 301 $scheme://www.[redacted].com/;
}
```

The first location block doesn't seem to be working at all. The second one does work. We want the second one to act as a "catch all" where as the first one should be used if it matches exactly.

I've tried:

- location ~*
- location
- location =

...but can't seem to get it to work.

edit:
I've now tried this and it still doesn't work.

```
location /index.cfm {
    rewrite index\.cfm\?/pagepath=Grain_Marketing $scheme://www.[redacted].com/grain-marketing/ permanent;
    return 301 $scheme://www.[redacted].com/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. It's because location doesn't seem to see arguments. This is the solution:

```
location /index.cfm {

    if ($args ~* pagepath=Grain_Marketing) {
        return 301 $scheme://www.[redacted].com/grain-marketing/;
    }

    return 301 $scheme://www.[redacted].com/;

}
```